# How to format value of input for the onBlur event in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Using [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik), how do I change the value of the input when the onBlur event occurs?

I have a Formik form with an input for phone number, and I want to format the phone number when the input blurs.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me:

```
<Formik
  render={props => (
    <Form>
      <Field
        name="phone"
        component={CustomInputComponent}
        onBlur={event => {
          const formatted = formatPhoneNumber(props.values['phone']);
          props.setFieldValue('phone', formatted);
          props.handleBlur(event);
        }}
      />
    </Form>
  )}
/>
```